# Scikit MultinomialNB predict_proba Gives Same Label Multiple Times

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm training a fairly simple model...

```
category_texts = [
    'this is a string here',
    'another string here',
    'once more with the words',
    'finally this string',
    'some other class with sentence in it'
]

category_labels = [
   'hasstring',
   'hasstring',
   'just words',
   'hasstring',
   'sentenceword'
]
```

I'm getting X by running it through TfidfVectorizor.

I'm training it with the MultinomialNB

```
clf = MultinomialNB()  
clf.fit(X,category_labels)
```

Now when I run

```
 clf.predict_proba('vectorizer.transform('a sentence with the word string')
```

I'm getting an output like:

```
hasstring     0.9823232421  
hasstring     0.6234394343  
sentenceword  0.3234394343
```

Is getting the same label with separate probabilities expected behavior?

Comment: I believe `clf.predict_proba` supplies a numpy array. How are you generating your output? Because the values in the numpy array do not correspond to values in `category_labels` at this point.

Comment: ugh... that was where I was making a mistake... I was using my label input list index rather than creating an indexed array of unique labels...

Comment: You might also want to consider the order in which the classifier is exposed to the labels when you match them with indices of the predicted array.